# Java: Self for static method calls within the same class

Tags: java, class, methods, self

Is it possible to do something like `self::` in PHP to not need to specify the class-name tro call a static method within the same class. See how I do it:

```
public class Foo
 public static void blaa() {...}
 public void foobar
 {
    Foo.blaa();
 }
```

but I'd like to it like

```
public class Foo
 public static void blaa() {...}
 public void foobar
 {
    _SOME_SORT_OF_SELF_.blaa();
 }
```

to not have to write down the classname over and over again...
same would go for static attributes. Instead of using `Foo.MY_ATTR` maybe accessing it via `_SOME_SORT_OF_SELF_.MY_ATTR`.

Possible?
Thanks

Comment: You *know*, use no prefix, it will work.

Comment: You can use `blaa()`. WIthout any prefix. I find it clearer with Foo.blaa(), but you're not forced to add the class name if it's the current class.

Comment: oh well, didn't know that. thanks. but yeah, it makes it a bit clearer to keep adding the class-name. but I'd even more like it via self. Same goes for attributes I suppose?

Comment: Yes, same for attributes. Non final static attributes are a design smell, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're trying to call a `static` method within the class it's defined in, you don't need to specify the type. (The rules get a little more complicated with nested classes).

For instance methods and variables, you can use the `this` keyword in your field access and method invocation expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Solution{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Hello";
    String b = "World";
    
    System.out.println(addTwoString(a,b));
  }
  public static String addTwoString(String a,String b){
     return a+" "+b;
  }
}
```